# JQuery animate sliding transition for the same element

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have knockout app that uses the same element for multiple pages. Some pages looks pretty much the same and might use the same template.

```
<section 
    data-bind="template: { name: templateName, afterRender: animatePageChange }">
</section>

animatePageChange: function() { 
        $('#content').hide(); 
        $('#content').show("slide", { direction: "right" },500); 
}
```

Now i want to let user know when he changes the page, e.g. old page slides out to left and new slides in from right.

How can i do slide if I have only one element and old content and new content are in it? Any plugins?

Plus would be nice considering direction of transition: when user goes back in history.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using jQuery.clone() to duplicate the element?